# Create "Multiple Tables" in ms word document using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want 2 tables in the word document like this:

Test ID :   TS1

Test Data : Sample Data

Test Description :  Sample Description

Test ID :   TS2

Test Data : Sample Data

Test Description :  Sample Description

For above tables i written code like this:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(); 
XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph(); 
XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun(); 

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Selenium\\yoj.doc")); 
for(int tabNo = 0;tabNo<=1;tabNo++)  //to get two tables
{           
    XWPFTable tab = document.createTable(10,2);
    XWPFTableRow row = tab.getRow(0);

    tab.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("Test Scenario ID: ");
    tab.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("TS1");
    tab.getRow(0).setCantSplitRow(true);
    tab.getRow(1).getCell(0).setText("Test Scenario Description: ");
    tab.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText("2");
    tab.getRow(2).getCell(0).setText("Test Data: ");
    tab.getRow(2).getCell(1).setText("3");
}
```

Iam getting output like this(Two tables are getting clubed) :

```
Test ID :   TS1
Test Data : Sample Data
Test Description :  Sample Description
Test ID :   TS2
Test Data : Sample Data
Test Description :  Sample Description
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line in the end of your boucle:

document.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak();